# Basic usage of plugin heroku-pg-transfer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to export my db from production app to local.

[As instructed by Heroku](http://www.higherorderheroku.com/articles/pgtransfer-is-the-new-taps/), I'm trying to do this with the Heroku plugin [heroku-pg-transfer](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-pg-transfer).

But I (really) need help understanding how to use it..

Do I need to specify the URL of my local db? And if so how do I find out the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is quite clear.

```
$ heroku help pg:transfer
Usage: heroku pg:transfer

 transfer data between databases

 -f, --from DATABASE  # source database, defaults to DATABASE_URL on the app
 -t, --to   DATABASE  # target database, defaults to local $DATABASE_URL
```

If you want to transfer from production to local, you need to swap `--to` to `--from`. Run `$ heroku config` and get the URL of your remote database. It will probably be under `DATABASE_URL` or similar.

Then run

```
$ heroku pg:transfer --from THE_DATABASE_URL --to YOUR_LOCAL_DATABASE
```

where database connection details are found in your database.yml file. You need to merge them in a connection string, with the format

```
postgres://username:password@localhost:5432/database-name
```

Here's an example

```
$ heroku pg:transfer --from postgres://heroku@someheroku:5432/database-heroku --to postgres://username:password@localhost:5432/database-name
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. Could you just please advice if there's any way to get the URL of the currently used local PG db? In databse.yml I do find the name (under `development:` and `database:`), but A) I do not have any username/password and B) I do not know the port.

Comment: That depends on your local postgresql setup. The port is by default 5432, the username and password depends on how you installed PG and configured the database.